# What credit the student must take?

Tags: uniform-distribution

The student plans the budget for the next year.

Expenses:

```
Tuition: 8400
Student Dormitory: 5400
```

Income:

```
Scholarship: 3000
Parent's help: 4000
```

Unknown expenses:

```
Food 900 - 1350
Transport 200 - 600
Books 400 - 800
Other 600 - 1200
```

Unknown income:

```
Restaurant job: 3000 - 5000
Library job: 2000 - 3000
```

Assume that unkonw expanses and incomes have a uniform distibution within the given limits. Conducting 1000 attempts, assess what credit the student must take so that with a probability of 95% he whould not have to take a higher interest rate loan.

Just guide me to the solution :) Because I have no idea how to start.

Ps. I can use Matlab

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I think I should sum up the compartments (the smallest to the smallest and the largest to the largest). Then, for each sample, generate randomly from the given interval. Am I correct?

Comment: Well, it appears that you are not supposed to find the answer analytically, but experimentally. I suggest using a computer for that

Comment: Could you take a look at https://pastebin.com/7s9TzK6c?

Comment: In your pastebin, you seem to assume that the total is uniformly distributed, when I read from the problem statement that the six individual iexpenses/incomes are to be assumed (independently) uniformly distributed. The sum of independently uniformly distributed random variables is not uniformly deistributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is to find the result by simulation.
Assuming you have a function $r(a,b)$ available that produces a uniformly distributed random number in the interval $[a,b]$, write a loop that computes (and stores in an array) the expression
$$8400+5400-3000-4000+r(300,1350)+r(200,600)+r(400,800)+r(600,1200)-r(3000,5000)-r(2000,3000) $$
a thousand times. Sort the resulting array. Then for any number $x$ in the range from the 950th to the 951st entry in that array, we have that $95\,\%$ of the generated numbers are $<x$.

*Remark:* The results of such experiments are of course subject to variation. See below where I performed the above calculations twice, giving rise to two different percentiles

[image]

Comment: Ok I got it :) I hope so :D https://pastebin.com/WfSMKSDD

Answer (score 1):

The expense $Z$ in total is 
$$Z=R+L-F-T-B-O-6800.$$
You‘ll easily calculate the expected value and the variance of $Z$ and from here the expected value and the variance of $Z_1+\cdots Z_{1000}$ and apply the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: Expected value: -3325.000000
Variance: 110208.333333 https://pastebin.com/7s9TzK6c Is it correct?

Comment: The central limit theorem does not seem to be appropriate for this problem.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Despite your diagram looks <censored> normal...